# Visual Studio hanging when adding new item to project, if not launched as administrator

Tags: visual-studio

Anyone knows why I would have to run Visual Studio (community 2019) as administrator to be able to add items to an existing project?
Every time I go to *Project > Add New Item...*, VS hangs. When I start VS as administrator, I don't have this issue.

VS2017 is installed on that same machine and I don't have this issue.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking there are several times when VS throughs these type of the errors, even this happened in mine reinstalling it helped me.